# What is the best sort algorithm for a random set of floats?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, sorting

A colleague of mine just put that question out in the air this afternoon, and somewhat left me curious. I'm versed with sorting algos, but lacking a formal degree in compsci / compeng (something I'm sorta averse to admitting), can't really place my finger on this one. :p

And oh yeah, this is mildly in the context of a C#/.NET implementation... just in case that changes things a bit.

Thanks guys. :)

Comment: How many floats? 3? 300? 3 million?

Comment: What makes float different from ints? Are you looking at performance measures other than asymptotic complexity?

Comment: To answer Greg, I don't really know. :D It was a general question, which makes me want to look for a general answer that is most probably optimal a majority of the time in general. :p User mdma provides a great argument for choosing between quicksort and mergesort without anchoring on a set amount of elements. :)

Comment: To answer Mau, I'd have to assume that working with floats (as opposed to ints) here has more to do with the question being of a .NET nature than the actual complexity of the algorithm. The choice probably boils down to choosing between quicksort and mergesort in general, but probably throwing in the fact that this is .NET and that we're working with floats changes it up a bit? Honestly, idk.

Comment: What does "best" mean? Most resistant to attack? Fastest? Shortest code? Cleverest? Fastest best possible performance? Fastest worst possible performance? Fastest average performance? Average given what distribution of data? You said *random* floats; random over what range and distribution? Does the sort have to be *stable*? Does it have to perform well on already-sorted lists? The question is far, far too vague to answer. *Best* requires a clear metric to make the comparison on.

Comment: @Eric would you be able to tell if a sort on primitives was stable or not? :-O

Comment: @glowcoder: Suppose you have a list of people sorted by name; if you then sort them by height, you might desire the sort-by-height algorithm to preserve alphabetical order in the event of a tie. An algorithm with that property might be "better" than one without.

Comment: @Eric but that's sorting a set of People, not a set of floats. I guess reading this (why was I reading an 8month old question anyway? \*shrug\*) I read it to be the float wasn't a key but actually the data as well. I guess this was something I read into it, as upon rereading it it's not explicit. Yes, for sure if the sort is on objects who happen to have a primitive as a key, you can tell if it's stable or not.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For fixed-length numbers, you're not restricted to comparison-based sorting algorithms, so `O(n*log(n))` is *not* the limit. [Radix Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) works in `O(n)`, and can be used quite conveniently due to the amazing property of IEEE 754 floats of being sorted correctly when their bit pattern is interpreted as integers.

Comment: This is something **totally** new to me. Thanks for sharing that. I'll read up on it when I find the time. :)

Comment: IEEE floats sort correctly as _sign-magnitude integers_ rather than two's complement integers. If you're going to be sorting negative numbers, one workaround is to complement every bit besides the high-order bit whenever the latter is set.

Comment: http://www.codercorner.com/RadixSortRevisited.htm discusses an approach to handling negative numbers

Answer (score 3):

I see that no one has mentioned [introsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort), which solves quick sort's `O(n^2)` worst case by switching to [heapsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort) when the recursion depth exceeds a certain threshold. This means that quick sort will not get the chance to degenerate, since its number of recursive calls will definitely be limited.

Another optimization is to switch to [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) whenever the number of elements of the sequence you are currently at is small (say 16).

This is how introsort could look:

```
void Introsort(int A[], int N, int left, int right, int depth)
{
    if ( left < right ) // note: this doesn't switch to insertion sort if right - left is small enough
    {   
        if ( (1 << depth) > N )
            Heapsort(A, left, right);
        else
        {
            int P = Partition(A, left, right);
            Introsort(A, N, left, P, depth+1);
            Introsort(A, N, P+1, right, depth+1);
        }
    }
}
```

This, combined with a good partition function (simply randomly choosing the pivot should be good enough for most purposes), will give you a very fast sorting algorithm.

There is also the choice of [radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort), which works really well, especially if your floats are not too big. From what I've seen though, it takes millions of elements for radix sort to outperform introsort.

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely note this one down. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a visual representetion on sorting-algorithms, check out this fantastic site:

[Sorting-algorithms.com](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/)

You'll get the feeling which works best in different cases, but my favorite is the merge sort, even though its not much better than quick sort.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically you compare algorithms using the [big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), which lets you compare which algorithm will be faster for "almost infinite" problem. In practise in most cases this is a very good staring point to compare how the algorithms will behave in real life.

The two most popular fast sort algorithms are MergeSort and quick sort. Merge Sort is guaranteed to be O(n log n) for any data, whereas quick sort has average time of O(n log n) and pessimistic time O(n^2). In practise most people use quick sort, because:

1. It happens almost in place naturally (I think you can make merge sort in place but it is tedious and will make it slower - it will increase the constant hidden in the O notation) - for large data sets this is an issue if the data does not fit into memory
2. It is faster in practise in most cases
3. You can modify it slightly (i.e. take the median of first, middle and last element for partitioning) so that it is very difficult to get data that would make it slow

To sum up I think quick sort will be quicker for your random floats, even though only looking at the O notation it seems worse - because you will get the expected O(n log n) and it will have a smaller constant than merge sort.

Answer (score 1):

A minor point to be aware of is that if any of your set are nan then the set isn't ordered and some sorting algorithms might give unexpected results or even crash.
I thinks its best to ensure that none of your numbers are nan before sorting.

For example (using gcc 3.4.6) applying qsort (ascending) to { 2, 1, nan, -1} gives  {1, 2, nan, -1}.

On the other hand inf and -inf are not a problem.