# Why does .NET 4.0 sort this array differently than .NET 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net

[This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5123659/138757) raised an interesting question about sorting double arrays with NaN values. The OP posted the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double[] someArray = { 4.0, 2.0, double.NaN, 1.0, 5.0, 3.0, double.NaN, 10.0, 9.0, 8.0 };

    foreach (double db in someArray)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(db);
    }

    Array.Sort(someArray);
    Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
    foreach (double db in someArray)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(db);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

When you run this under the .NET 3.5 framework, the array is sorted as follows:

`1,4,NaN,2,3,5,8,9,10,NaN`

When you run it under .NET 4.0, the array is sorted somewhat more logically:

`NaN,NaN,1,2,3,4,5,8,9,10`

I can understand why it would sort weirdly in .NET 3.5 (because NaN is not equal to, less than, or greater than, anything). I can also understand why it would sort the way it does in .NET 4.0. My question is, why did this change from 3.5 to 4.0? And where is the Microsoft documentation for this change?

Comment: I suspect there is no good reason; probably just an oversight by Microsoft.

Comment: I know they fixed a couple of things here - for example there was a bug with non-reflective string sorts - but I don't have any citations - only examples.

Comment: Surprisingly, [What's new in .NET 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868.aspx) doesn't have any mention of this particular change.

Comment: Sounds like a stupid bug in .net 3.5 that was fixed. No idea why they used a broken comparer in the first place, especially since according to pst `double.CompareTo` is correct in .net 3.5.

Comment: They probably didn't write any unit tests for it ;)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It's a bug fix.  The feedback report with the bug details [is here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120419145910/http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/363379/bug-in-list-double-sort-in-list-which-contains-double-nan). Microsoft's response to the bug report:

> Note that this bug affects the following:

> - Array.Sort(), where the array contains Double.NaN

- Array.Sort(), where the array contains Single.NaN
- any callers of above, for example on List.Sort(), where list contains Double.NaN

> This bug will be fixed in the next major version of the runtime; until then you can work around this by using a custom IComparer that does the correct sorting. As mentioned in the workaround comments, don't use Comparer.Default, because this is special-cased with a shortcut sort routine that doesn't handle NaN correctly. Instead, you can provide your own comparer that provides an equivalent comparision, but won't be special-cased.

Answer (score 6):

Not really an answer, but perhaps a clue... You can reproduce the weird 3.5 behavior in 4.0 with this code:

```
void Main()
{
    double[] someArray = { 4.0, 2.0, double.NaN, 1.0, 5.0, 3.0, double.NaN, 10.0, 9.0, 8.0 };
    Array.Sort(someArray, CompareDouble);
    someArray.Dump();
}

int CompareDouble(double a, double b)
{
    if (a > b)
        return 1;
    if (a < b)
        return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

Here, both `a > b` and `a < b` return false if a or b is `NaN`, so the `CompareDouble` method returns 0, so `NaN` is considered equal to everything... This gives the same result as in 3.5:

```
1,4,NaN,2,3,5,8,9,10,NaN
```

Comment: +1 Really, it's all about default parameter values (by default, 3.5 is sorting using CompareDouble), in 4.0, situation had been improved

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the code for the .NET 3.5 runtime to verify this, but I'm thinking they fixed a bug in the default comparer for `double` to bring it into line with [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9cczk1sc.aspx).

According to that document, `Double.Compare` treats `NaN` as equal to `PositiveInfinity` and `NegativeInfinity`, and less than any other value.

The documentation is the same for .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0, so I have to think that this was a bug fix to make the code work as documented.

EDIT:

After reading the comments in the linked question, I have to think that the problem wasn't in `Double.Compare`, but rather in whatever method `Array.Sort` (which is what `List.Sort` depends on) uses to compare `Double` values.  Somehow, I don't think it's really `Double.Compare`.

Answer (score 2):

[This is my response shameless ripped from the other post. It would be nice is someone explored this further -- `double.CompareTo` and `double.CompareTo(double)` are well-defined, as indicated below so I suspect there is some `Array.Sort` magic happening for the specific type.]

`Array.Sort(double[])`: *doesn't seem to be using `CompareTo(double[])` as expected and this may very well be a bug -- note the difference in Array.Sort(object[]) and Array.Sort(double[]) below*. I would love clarification/corrections on the following.

First, the [`double.CompareTo(T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9cczk1sc.aspx) method documentation -- **this ordering is well-defined according to the documentation**:

> > *Less than zero*:
> >     This instance is less than value.
> >     -or-
> >     This instance is not a number (NaN) and value is a number.
> >
> > *Zero*:
> >     This instance is equal to value.
> >     -or-
> >     Both this instance and value are not a number (NaN), PositiveInfinity, or NegativeInfinity.
> >
> > *Greater than zero*:
> >     This instance is greater than value.
> >     -or-
> >     This instance is a number and value is not a number (NaN).

In LINQPad (3.5 and 4, both have same results):

```
0d.CompareTo(0d).Dump();                  // 0
double.NaN.CompareTo(0d).Dump();          // -1
double.NaN.CompareTo(double.NaN).Dump();  // 0
0d.CompareTo(double.NaN).Dump();          // 1
```

Using `CompareTo(object)` has the same results:

```
0d.CompareTo((object)0d).Dump();                  // 0
double.NaN.CompareTo((object)0d).Dump();          // -1
double.NaN.CompareTo((object)double.NaN).Dump();  // 0
0d.CompareTo((object)double.NaN).Dump();          // 1
```

So that's not the problem.

Now, from the [`Array.Sort(object[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tf1f0bc%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) documentation -- **there is no use of `>`, `<` or `==` (according to the documentation)** -- just `CompareTo(object)`.

> > Sorts the elements in an entire one-dimensional Array using the `IComparable` implementation of each element of the Array.

Likewise, [`Array.Sort(T[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwx6zbd4%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) uses `CompareTo(T)`.

> > Sorts the elements in an entire Array using the IComparable(Of T) generic interface implementation of each element of the Array.

Let's see:

LINQPad (4):

```
var ar = new double[] {double.NaN, 0, 1, double.NaN};
Array.Sort(ar);
ar.Dump();
// NaN, NaN, 0, 1
```

LINQPad (3.5):

```
var ar = new double[] {double.NaN, 0, 1, double.NaN};
Array.Sort(ar);
ar.Dump();
// NaN, 0, NaN, 1
```

LINQPad (3.5) -- **NOTE THE ARRAY IS OF OBJECT** and the behavior is "expected" per the `CompareTo` contract.

```
var ar = new object[] {double.NaN, 0d, 1d, double.NaN};
Array.Sort(ar);
ar.Dump();
// NaN, NaN, 0, 1
```

Hmm. Really. In conclusion:

*I HAVE NO IDEA* -- but I *suspect* there is some "optimization" resulting in `CompareTo(double)` not being invoked.

Happy coding.

Comment: This is correct. The `<` operator of the C# language is not a total order because of its `NaN` behavior. It can't be used with sort algorithms for that reason. The `double.CompareTo` method (and `double`'s implementation of `IComparable` and `IComparable<>`) gives a "good" total order. The `Comparer<double>.Default` instance also gets this "good" ordering. According to the documentation for both .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0, the `Sort` method should use the good algorithm. Like you specualted, .NET 3.5 had an "optimization" for some types, including `double`, which "forgot" to handle `NaN`s.