# Behaviour of List<T>.Sort in .NET 4.5 changed from .NET 4.0?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

I have the following test inside a project targeting .NET 4.0:

```
[TestFixture]
public class Donkey
{
    [Test]
    public void TestListSorting()
    {
        var expected = new[]
                    {
                                MockRepository.GenerateStub<IComparable>(),
                                MockRepository.GenerateStub<IComparable>()
                    };

        var sorted = new List<IComparable>(expected);

        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, sorted);
        sorted.Sort();
        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, sorted);

    }
}
```

If I run it on a machine with only .NET 4.0 installed, it fails. 
If I run it on a machine with only .NET 4.5 installed, it passes.

I am assuming that in .NET 4.5 the implementation of `Sort` has been changed to maintain order when sorting a list of objects which each return `0` from `CompareTo`.

**Now, put aside the obvious insanity of this test. I know it's crazy to rely on this kind of behaviour.**

*Surely* this is a breaking change? It is not listed on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh367887.aspx) about compatibility between .NET 4.0 and 4.5.

Is there a reason for this? Am I missing something? Is there another page which shows actual breaking changes? Should I just have a sit down and stop panicking?

Comment: [The spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6(v=vs.110).aspx) still says it uses a QuickSort that may not preserve order.

Comment: Although [you're not the first to notice](http://twitter.com/skolima/statuses/237549909719539712). (Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12156627/string-sorting-performance-degradation-in-vs2010-vs-vs2008) mentions it being changed to an "introspective sort", which is not stable but is a different algorithm.)

Comment: What might have happened is that QuickSort was modified in a way that makes this trivial sort appear stable. (Different choice of pivot maybe.) I'm not sure how to construct a test case that would conclusively prove whether the sorting algorithm in use is now stable or not, but comparing two elements isn't it.

Comment: Another way to see if the difference is there is `var li = new List<string> { "first", "second", }; li.Sort((x, y) => 0);`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I've answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12156627/string-sorting-performance-degradation-in-vs2010-vs-vs2008/12184039#12184039) to this before.  The sorting method has changed between 4.5 and 4.0, from a quick sort to an [introspective sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort).

It's actually faster, but still it is not a stable sort<sup>1</sup>, that is, one that has the same output for every execution by preserving the order of equal items.  Since no implementation of `List.Sort` is a stable sort, I don't think you've run your unit test above enough times to have it error in both runtimes?

I tried to reproduce it myself with equivalent code and a comparer that returns 0.  Sometimes the list order is preserved and sometimes it is not, in both .NET 4.5 and .NET 3.5.

Even if it did change the sort type from stable to unstable, **its not a breaking change**.  The type of sort used and the exact output is not part of the contract for `List.Sort`.  All that the method contract guarantees is that your items will be in sorted order according to the comparer used.

<del>It is interesting, though, because the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6.aspx) still says it uses QuickSort (via `Array.Sort`), but this is not the case if you were to step through the .NET reference source.</del>

---

<sup><sub>1</sub></sup> <sub>By definition of using a mix of `QuickSort` and `HeapSort`, it should be an unstable sort.  Even David Musser, the designer of the algorithm states in [his paper](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~musser/gp/introsort.ps):</sub>

> <sub>Introsort, like quicksort, is not stable -- does not preserve the order of equivalent elements -- so there is still a need to have a separate requirement for a stable sorting routine.</sub>

Comment: +1: Thanks for that great explanation in your other answer.  I'm slow, so I didn't understand the other answers below until I read that.

Comment: The MSDN documentation has been updated to reflect this change since this answer was written.

Answer (score 5):

[The spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for `List.Sort` says that the sort used is unstable and thus may not preserve the ordering of equal elements; it doesn't specify a *particular* re-ordering of equal elements, so you can't really call this change a breaking change.

Answer (score 3):

As @Rawling said, have a look at [the documentation for `Sort()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6.aspx):

> This implementation performs an unstable sort; that is, if two elements are equal, their order might not be preserved.

So, you're trying to test something that is explicitly documented as undefined. That is not a breaking change.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any change. As others already wrote, both versions perform an unstable sort. Which means that you cannot rely on order of elements that compare as equals. Their order may or may not change during sort. It certainly isn't a breaking change.

See: [Documentation of List< T >.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> This implementation performs an unstable sort; that is, if two elements are equal, their order might not be preserved

Doesn't look like the order is reliable therefore the test is void. Also, why are you testing the `Sort` method anyway? Seems like an unnecessary test to me.

Answer (score 0):

Questions like this often come up with new framework versions. There are some for the 3.5 → 4.0 transition [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123886/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338380/).

For this particular change of versions, the difference comes up already whith an array or `List<>` of two elements, as your question shows. Another simple example is:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace SortTest
{
  static class Program
  {
    static void Main()
    {
      var arr = new[] { new { Name = "Mary", Age = 17, }, new { Name = "Louise", Age = 17, }, };

      Array.Sort(arr, (x, y) => x.Age.CompareTo(y.Age));

      Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", arr.Select(x => x.Name)));
    }
  }
}
```

With .NET 4.0 this prints `Louise,Mary`. The elements are swapped. However, with .NET 4.5 it prints `Mary,Louise`. Note that the two girls have the same age.

`List<>.Sort` instance method and `Array.Sort` static method are *documented* to be non-stable sorts. They are free to leave elements of equal "size" in any order they want. So your code must not make any assumptions about what order equivalent elements come in.

In contrast, Linq's `OrderBy` method performs a stable sort. So

```
var ordered = arr.OrderBy(x => x.Age);
```

is *required* to *not* swap Mary and Louise, given that they have the same `Age`.