# NUnit Test Runner and Visual Studio NUnit Test runner get different results for a test

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit

In [the geometry library I am writing](https://bitbucket.org/Clearspan/geometry-class-library) I have a strange test that passes when I run using the NUnit test runner in Visual Studio, but when it runs on the regular NUnit runner it fails. I am testing the same DLLs

Here is the test:

```
    [Test()]
    public void Line_Sort()
    {
        Line line1 = new Line(PointGenerator.MakePointWithInches(3, 2, 5), PointGenerator.MakePointWithInches(5, 3, 7)); //intersects at -1, 0, 1
        Line line2 = new Line(PointGenerator.MakePointWithInches(6, 0, 0), PointGenerator.MakePointWithInches(-5, 3, -1)); //intersects at 6, 0, 0
        Line line3 = new Line(PointGenerator.MakePointWithInches(1, 1, 5), PointGenerator.MakePointWithInches(2, 2, 4)); //intersects at 0, 0, 6
        Line line4 = new Line(PointGenerator.MakePointWithInches(4, 10, 1), PointGenerator.MakePointWithInches(4, 5, 2)); //intersects at 4, 0, 3
        Line line5 = new Line(PointGenerator.MakePointWithInches(4, 2, 2), PointGenerator.MakePointWithInches(4, 2, 1)); //doesnt intersect

        List<Line> lines = new List<Line> { line2, line3, line5, line4, line1 };

        lines.Sort();

        lines[0].Should().Be(line1);
        lines[1].Should().Be(line3);
        lines[2].Should().Be(line4);
        lines[3].Should().Be(line2);
        lines[4].Should().Be(line5);
    }
```

It seems that the sort function works differently in the two cases. Causing the test to fail in the NUnit runner where the list order is not equal to the expected.

[image]

[image]

What could cause this? And how can I fix it? Our build server behaves the same as the NUnit runner

Comment: Why it fails might be useful information...

Comment: .NET version  problem perhaps? http://stackoverflow.com/q/12461328/32093